# Updating value at each iteration using python

Tags: python, iteration

I want to get updated value of Pw at each iteration. For first iteration, it takes minimum value of first row and subtracts from Pw1. For second iteration, I want it to take this updated Pw (not Pw1) and subtract the minimum of second row.

```py
import numpy as np
Pe=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
Pw1=100
Pe_min=Pe.min(axis=1)

for i in range(4):
    Pw=np.zeros(4)
    Pw[i]=Pw1-Pe_min[i]
    print(Pw)
```

The current output is

```
99
95
91
87
```

The output I am seeking is

```
99
94
85
72
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically,
You should update the Pw1 value in the each iteration. So you can add

```
Pw1-=Pe_min[i]
```

Full Code;

```
import numpy as np
Pe=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
Pw1=100
Pe_min=Pe.min(axis=1)
for i in range(4):
    Pw=np.zeros(4)
    Pw[i]=Pw1-Pe_min[i]
    Pw1-=Pe_min[i]
    print(Pw)
```

Comment: How do I access the updated values of Pw? For instance, I want to call 85. If I use ```Pw```, I get the output: ```[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , 72]```

Comment: If you're asking after termination of loop, you can not directly access. Because you declared the array in the loop, this is an local variable and you cannot access out of loop. But you can declare the array before the loop and you can do all of this process same.